# New offset Dashing argument in 12.3

Tags: bugs, documentation, linux, graphics

**Bug introduced in 12.3 and fixed in 13.0**

After finding out that in 12.3 two new optional arguments have been added to `Dashing`, I decided to have a look at them. Unfortuantely, I don't understand the way the *offset* argument works.
The documentation has an example

```
Table[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}], Dashing[{.1, .05}, o], Red, 
   Opacity[.5], Thickness[.05], Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}], {o, {-0.05, 
   0, 0.05}}]
```

which for me gives a slightly different output than what is in the documentation, namely I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference is that for me all the lines start at the bottom left corner with a dash, whereas in the documentation the first line starts with a gap, the second with a dash, and the final one from the middle of a dash.

Also, changing `o` to

```
{-0.15, 0, 0.15}
```

at the end of the command (or to other values) does not change anything for me. I am not going to post more images, as it literally looks exactly the same as the one above.

The documentation explains *offset* as:

"offset is specified as a fraction of the total width of the graph, and it may be positive or negative. If offset is not specified, it is 0."

Based on that I played with the `Thickness` parameter in the command, thinking that this affects the width of the dashes, but that only led to the latter becomming thicker and varying *offset* did not produce any visible changes.

I am on Mathematica 12.3.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.

What is *offset* supposed to do and how do I use it?

**UPDATE:** Would it be possible for somebody to confirm whether this also happens on Mac OS or Windows, thank you.

Comment: Trying this in 12.3.0 on Pop!_OS, it appears this is a bug. The final example in the documentation is an animation of varying offset that doesn't actually do anything. `Animate[Graphics[{Dashing[{.04, .04}, a], 
   Table[Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[b], Sin[b]}}], {b, 0, 
     2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/20}]}], {a, 0.64, 0}]`

Comment: @CarlLange That animation does not seem to do anything for me either. I will wait a bit longer (especially after my question on CapForm which was also thought of as a bug initially, but turned out not to be) before reporting it or anything. It will be nice if somebody not using Linux also reports on it.

Comment: @ThunderBiggi, why don't you edit your question to add a request for people to check if the bug is reproducible on different platforms? I have reported bugs or other problems to Wolfram Support with links to Mathematica StackExchange and it's clear that they do look at the information we share here seriously. You do have to report to support though and share with them the link to the Q&A.

Comment: @rhermans thank you for the suggestion, I did update the post to ask for a report from another OS. 
When I report the problem I will share the link to this question.

Comment: The wonkiness with offset is a bug on Linux. It will behave better in the next version.

Comment: @ihojnicki Could you elaborate on how you know this?

Comment: @CarlLange, I reviewed the changeset that fixed it. :)

Comment: @ihojnicki so do I report it or not then?

Comment: @ThunderBiggi, since it had already been reported, I do not think a new bug report is necessary.

Comment: @ihojnicki and others, I'm assuming this was fixed in V13 and was a Linux-only bug.  Please edit/correct the question if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MichaelE2 it is fixed for me, so your edit is good